# What command should I use to make my void function display a paticular table using a variable from the function in the where clause?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I basically have a void function that creates a tuple on a existing table. Now at the end of the function I want display the table with the updated tuple. I am running it problems when trying to do this.

This is the statement I am using:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE IDNo = idnumber';
-- (idnumber is a variable that is assigned a value in the function)
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: column "idnumber" does not exist.
```

Can someone please help me find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the actual query, you would want to do something like this:

`execute 'select * from table where IDNo = $1' using idnumber;`

With the key being the `$1` and the `USING` clause to interpolate the variable.

That should resolve the column error regarding `idnumber`.

However, I'm not quite sure what you mean by:

> display the table with the updated tuple

Do you mean you want to return all the rows in the table including the newly added row? Or just the newly added row? or something else?

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

The substitution variables, e.g. `$1, $2, $3...` are *scoped* (i.e. unique) to each separate `execute` statement. So if you had two statements, the first with 3 variables, the second with three, you could use `$1, $2, $3` in each and they would refer to the variables mentioned in the `USING` clause for that individual statement.

See the *Postgres* [Basic Statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html) doc, specifically the section entitled **40.5.4. Executing Dynamic Commands**, for more detail.

**Second edit in response to *display* comments from OP:**

When `execute`ing statements, they won't output the way, say, a `select` statement would if you were doing it within *psql* or *pgadmin*. Rather, you have a couple different options, depending on what you ultimately want to do.

First, you could use an `INTO` clause to put the result into a *record* (although how you do this depends on whether it's just one row or many rows).

You would need to declare it in that case in the declaration section something like this: `foo RECORD;`

And then add `INTO foo` before the `USING` clause. If it complains about more than one record, you could add `LIMIT 1` clause at the end of the query.

You could then do whatever else you wanted to with that record, including `RAISE NOTICE` with interpolating the record's columns, which would print it to the console.

If you want the entire table, and you want it to "display" more like *psql* or similar would (that is, *return* the rows obtained), you would want to have the function return a `setof` a specific type.

So it may then look something like this:

```
create function get_table() returns setof table as $$
  execute 'select * from table where IDNo = $1' using idnumber;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

Where `table` is the name of the table you want. If you just want to return the existing rows of the table, this sort of query should work. It would then "display" in a client (e.g. *psql*, etc.) as the result set.

If you want to modify that (say, by dynamically adding some columns), then you would need to define that new type specifically, and then use that as the type being returned.

See the [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions) for more details. The wiki content is pretty old (Postgres 7.x vintage), but it generally still applies.

Comment: If I were to have another statement like this would I have to use $1 again or something else?

Comment: Your solution got rid of the error. But the tables dont actually print. The program runs as expected expect the tables dont display where they are supposed to.

Comment: Added info to my answer for your first comment. Re: the second, that gets to my question as to exactly what you want to happen by tables "displaying".

Comment: I want the tables to display after executing the function.

Comment: You want the rows of the table output to the console you mean? And for what tables? Just the `table` you `select`ed from?

Comment: Yes, the table i mentioned in my select statment. And the same way from another table if I choose to make another statment just like the one above. My only problem now is that the table is just not showing :/

Comment: I have one doubt, if i greated the create_table function how would that function know what id_number is since that variable is in the another function

Comment: Have `id_number` be an argument to the new function. Then it can be used with the  same type of `$1` / `USING` interpolation syntax in the query. You could have the other function where it is defined pass it to this new function.